# Mac and Apache: permission to chmod -R g+rx and still Forbidden

Tags: php, ajax, apache, permissions

I'm trying to send with Ajax (method `GET`) some data to `/root/Site/test/index.php` building the link as follows:

```
/root/Site/test/index.php/section/option/value
```

But I get this message from the server:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>403 Forbidden</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Forbidden</h1>
<p>You don't have permission to access /root/Site/test/index.php/section/option/value
on this server.</p>
</body></html>
Forbidden
```

Following what I've read, I have set the permissions of both the `test` folder and after even of the `Site` to `sudo chmod -R g+rx` (I've tried also without `sudo`), but I still get the error.
Why?!

Comment: I would check apache log files

Comment: is `/root/Site/etc...` within your site's document root? Is that how Apache is actually mapping requests to your server's filesystem?

Comment: Are you using the standard Mac OS X Apache, and in that case, what version?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Yes, `Server version: Apache/2.2.22 (Unix)`

Comment: @MarcB yes `root` is a folder in `Users/ghego1/Sites/root`, and then I have set a local host having as root the `root` folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also double check that you have "Allow from all" in your httpd.conf directory clause.

```
<Directory "/home/domain/www">
        Options +Indexes FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI
        AllowOverride AuthConfig FileInfo
            Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: I fear that I don't, I have checked the file in the etc/Apache2 folder and it seems that this might be the problem... Do you know how I can access the httpd.conf file with Terminal? (with textedit it says I don't have permissions...).

Comment: "sudo nano /etc/apache2/httpd.conf". Then after you modify the file save the changes and restart apache.

Comment: One last question sorry! If I have set my host folder to be the `test` folder in `Users/ghego1/Sites/root/test`, the Diretory to specify is only `/test` right?

Comment: No, you just can't put /test. You need to put the absolute path to your folder.  /Users/ghego1/Sites/root/test   . Notice that you missed the starting slash.

Comment: I've tried several times but still getting the same error! Any idea?

Comment: Hi, Double check that you have the same path in the directory clause and in the documentroot clause.

Comment: Yes!! Success! You're a genius (not mac ones! :-) ). Thank's so much!!

Answer (score 1):

By using:

```
sudo chmod -R g+rx
```

You are just granting the read and execution permissions for the group, and the apache service runs as a daemon, the user that runs apache is different than the file owner and may not belong to the group of the file.

```
sudo chmod 755 filename
```

Using this you are allowing everybody to read the file and only write permission for the owner.

For the folder do the same with -R to apply to all its internal files.

```
sudo chmod -R 755 foldername
```

** Do not assign permission 777 because that will make the file vulnerable to undesired modifications. Unless you are 100% 777 is a security issue.

Comment: I must admit I am not sure of having understood what you mean, anyway I've tried `sudo chmod 755 filename` on `index.php` but it still tells me forbidden..

Comment: @ghego1 I think he means `chmod -R go+rx` instead of just `chmod g+rx`.

Comment: Ok let me explain better: chmod means "change file modifiers". Using g+rx means: people that belongs to the file's group can r(read) and x(execute it). But apache is running in your system as a daemon(service) and was launched by a system user(on debian is www-data). Because this user may not be member of the group that your file belongs. Then is good to give read permission to the file to everyone. Using permission 755 means (owner can read and execute, group can read, everyone can read). By doing this you are granting everyone read permission to the file.

Answer (score 0):

The server is probably accessing the files under another user. It's www-data:www-data in Debian Linux installs. Try giving it chmod -R 777 or chmod -R a+rwx instead.

The other option is that you didn't configure httpd.conf properly, so check that as well.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility, since your path is

```
 /root/Site/test/index.php/section/option/value
                 ^^^^^^^^^--- actual php script
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^-- extra stuff
```

make sure that Apache's `AcceptPathInfo` ([docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#acceptpathinfo)) option is enabled. Without that, the extra bits will be seen as parts of the url path, and not as parameters for the PHP script's path_info.